# How does gitk view associate to the local and remote repository paths?

Tags: repository, version-control, gitk

I am trying to find source code in our project and I have access to the view with gitk but I don't have a local copy.  Now I want to get a local copy.  How do I interpret gitk presentation to extract the code into my local repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to edit my project/.repo/manifests/default.xml to include the path relative to its neighboring git projects.